# fish_title displays function body instead of name after bringing to the foreground

Tags: shell, fish

Given fish function

```
function nv --description 'nvim in style'
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8 ~/nvim-osx64/bin/nvim -u ~/.config/nvim/init.lua $argv
end
```

And `fish_title`:

```
function fish_title
    set -q argv[1]; or set argv (prompt_pwd)
    echo $argv;
end
```

I'd expect `argv[1]` being `nv`. Instead I'm getting function's body.

Is there any way to have function name as an argument in case of user defined functions\aliases?

PS: as the title suggests this can be reproduced only after sending the process to the background and then to the foreground with `fg`.

Comment: What's your `fish --version`?  I'm not able to reproduce under 3.3.1, so I'd like to confirm your release before I dig deeper.  Since I don't have Neovim installed, I just used a simple "sleep 3" alias.  The alias/function name displayed in the title while running, rather than the function body.

Comment: Even with a function wrapper around `vi`, I still see the function name in the title when running.  But I don't see anything in the fish release notes that would have changed this behavior at any point.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds `fish, version 3.3.1`

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds The issue exists only with bringing process foreground after `ctrl+z`. Try doing this with sleep 5, for example. Then send program to the background and `fg` it back.

Comment: Now *that* I can reproduce!  Thanks.  You should edit that into the question.  I'll noodle on it, but it may just be a bug.  Also, one of the fish contributors checks in here occasionally and may have a suggestion.

Comment: Oddly, using `:shell` inside `vi` gives me something slightly different -- It changes to `fish ~`, but doesn't go back to `nv filename` after returning from the shell to `vi`.  The title remains "fish <path>" even back in vi.

Comment: This problem appears to occur even with the default `fish_title` function.